# Updating a Json column that contains a JsonArray using Json_transform() function in Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition

Tags: json, oracle, spring-boot, oracle19c

I have a table that keeps `USER` data.

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "USERS"
(
    "ID" NUMBER(16,0) PRIMARY KEY,
    "USER_NAME" VARCHAR2(85) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    "IDENTIFICATION_TYPE" NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL REFERENCES IDENTIFICATION_TYPES(ID),
    "IDENTIFICATION_CODE" VARCHAR2(24) NOT NULL,
    "TRADING_CODE" VARCHAR2(85) NULL,
    "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(48) NOT NULL,
    "SALT" VARCHAR2(24) NOT NULL,
    "FLAGS" NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    "PROFILE" NCLOB NOT NULL CONSTRAINT profile_json CHECK ("PROFILE" IS JSON),
    "SETTINGS" NCLOB NOT NULL CONSTRAINT settings_json CHECK ("SETTINGS" IS JSON),   
  UNIQUE(IDENTIFICATION_TYPE,IDENTIFICATION_CODE)
);
```

As you can see I have a Json column named `SETTINGS`.

And the data that will be kept in this column looks like :

```
{
  "lang" : "fa-IR",
  "cols" : [],
  "watch_lists" :
  {
    "list_1" : [5,6,7],
    "list_2" : [8,9],
    "list_3" :[1,2,3]
  }
}
```

Now my application receives an updated list of `watch_lists` that I want to replace with current one.

After some research at first I could write the following query using `JSON_MERGEPATCH()` function:

```
UPDATE USERS 
SET SETTINGS = JSON_MERGEPATCH(SETTINGS, '{ "watch_lists": { "liist_1": [4,5],"liist_2": [1,3,5] }}' returning clob pretty)
WHERE USER_NAME = 'admin'
```

But I found that `JSON_MERGEPATCH()` will merge the updated list with current one, but I needed to replace it, then finally I understood that I need to use the `JSON_TRANSFORM()` function in order to replace the list, so I wrote the following query:

```
UPDATE USERS 
SET SETTINGS = JSON_TRANSFORM(SETTINGS,
               SET '$.watch_lists' =
                   '{ "liist_1": [4,5],"liist_2": [1,3,5] }'
                   FORMAT JSON)
WHERE USER_NAME = 'admin'
```

But now it throws an exception :

```
SQL Error [1747] [42000]: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

I could not find the reason of this error to resolve it.

Can anyone help me?

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: I deleted my answer. I thought at first glance that was a typo mistake. My bad.

Comment: Which version and patch level of 19c are you using? It appears that it just isn't recognising the `json_transform()` function - but it isn't clear exactly when it was added. It isn't mentioned in the "what's new" sections - though `json_mergepatch` is. It's touted as [a new 21c feature](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Changes-in-This-Release-for-Oracle-Database-SQL-Language-Reference.html#GUID-3C11D3A9-8B14-4DCC-B212-B7FE57EE81E8) but, like e.g.  SQL macros, seems to have been back-ported to a later 19.x release. it seems to work in 19.11, for instance.

Comment: I can confirm, it *does not* work in `19.3.0.0.0` @AlexPoole

Comment: Right... it isn't helpful when they [add things to the generic 19c docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/oracle-sql-function-json_transform.html#GUID-7BED994B-EAA3-4FF0-824D-C12ADAB862C1) without making it clear when it will work. They do for some things; so this seems to be a documentation bug really.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber but what about this link?? as it is wroten on the top left in the path, this link is the documentation of Release 19 and is describing Json_transform() :
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/oracle-sql-function-json_transform.html#GUID-7BED994B-EAA3-4FF0-824D-C12ADAB862C1

Comment: @AlexPoole would you please check my last comment, thanks

Comment: @Sobhan - check my comments; the function didn't originally exist in 19c; it was added later (some time after 19.3), apparently as a back-port of new 21c functionality, and was added to the documentation at the same time, presumably. But the docs don't state which versions it works in, which is unhelpful.

Comment: @AlexPoole I got it, you are right completely , thanks for your help and the time you spent on my issue!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It somehow seems that `JSON_TRANSFORM` is available starting with 21c version (and was *backported* in higher release of 19c).

Anyway you can use `JSON_MERGEPATH` with a *two step* approach.

Reset the attribute first and than set it to the new value:

```
UPDATE USERS 
SET SETTINGS = JSON_MERGEPATCH(SETTINGS,              
                   '{ "watch_lists": null}'
                  )
WHERE USER_NAME = 'admin'
;
UPDATE USERS 
SET SETTINGS = JSON_MERGEPATCH(SETTINGS,              
                   '{ "watch_lists": { "liist_1": [4,5],"liist_2": [1,3,5] }}'
                  )
WHERE USER_NAME = 'admin'
;
```

Comment: thanks for your help, it works fine and can resolve my issue, but I prefer to do it in one transaction, this way i must have 2 DB call per request and looks not efficient for me, right??
anyway If I can not find a solution, I will use and approve your solution